# Docker image failed - port 8080 used

Tags: macos, docker, nginx, docker-compose, port

I'am trying to build docker containers on my MAC but I'm getting an error:

> ERROR: for myapp_app-nginx_1  Cannot start service app-nginx: Ports are not available: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:80: bind: address already in use

I tried everything. I don't have nginx globally installed so i don't know what is the problem.

This is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  app-nginx:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: .docker/dev/nginx/Dockerfile
      args:
        PHP_HOSTNAME: app-php
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/usr/share/nginx/html:cached
    networks:
      - myapp-io
    ports:
      - 80:80
    depends_on:
      - app-php

  app-php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: .docker/dev/php/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html:cached
    networks:
      - myapp-io
    depends_on:
      - app-db
    command:
      - /bin/sh
      - -c
      - |
        composer install
        php bin/console myapp:db:init-or-update
        php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate
        php-fpm

  app-db:
    image: postgres:10-alpine
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=abc
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=abc
    volumes:
      - db-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data:cached
    networks:
      - uhub-io
    ports:
      - 5432:5432

  app-node:
    image: node:12.10-buster
    working_dir: /home/node/app
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/home/node/app:cached
    networks:
      - myapp-io
    command:
      - /bin/sh
      - -c
      - |
        [ -d node_modules/.bin ] || npm install
        [ -f dist/apps/myapp-app/index.html ] || npm run build:docker

volumes:
  db-volume:

networks:
  myapp-io:
    name: myapp-io
```

Update: I run command **netstat -an | grep LISTEN** and got:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4SRd.png)

What should I do? I am new on mac.

Comment: First off, this is your `docker-compose.yml` not your `Dockerfile`. Second, have you tried another port? It seems that a process or a container is currently using the port on your host system - hence the `address already in use` error message. Please try to list all process with open tcp connections on your host via `netstat -tulpn`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not port 8080, it's 80, and you must have something listening on that port.

For example, use `netstat -an | grep LISTEN` to check every process that it's listening, and then find out which one is using port 80.

Comment: ...you got a PNG file from running `netstat`?  That'd be pretty unusual.